# Can't make dump work

Tags: python, django, mysql

I'm trying to upload my database to pythonanywhere, I'm using the console to make the upload, but I can't I been trying a lot of thing, but I always get a syntax error.

my command looks like this:

```
mysqldump -u mediexcel2 -p -h mysql.server mediexcel2$basedatosmediexcelprt < Dump.sql;
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump -u mediexcel2 -p -h mysql.server mediexcel2$basedatosmediexcelprt < Du' at line 1
```

I have done it without the mysqldump in the begining, without the name of the data base, etc. and nothing seems to work.

Comment: I'm confused... `mysqldump` normally tries to dump a database, not upload one. In that case you should replace `<` (input) with `>` (output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, seems like you are trying to run this command from within the mysql client, aren't you? Log out from mysql client ("quit") and run your command directly from shell. Also it's "mysql" for using the dump, and "mysqldump" for creating it.

Edit: Just to be clear:

```
mysqldump ... > dumpfile
```

creates "dumpfile" including SQL statements, but

```
mysql .... < dumpfile
```

uses the "dumpfile" (actually runs the SQL statements in the "dumpfile").

HTH,

Comment: I was using the mysql client, but I still have and other error,                    
Enter password: 
    ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 1: Access denied for user 'mediexcel2'@'%' to database 'mediexceldb'

Comment: You need to put single quotes around the database name and, like Christian David says, use mysql instead of mysqldump.  Copy and paste (or type exactly) this, excluding the "[[[" and "]]]" around it: [[[mysql -u mediexcel2 -p -h mysql.server 'mediexcel2$basedatosmediexcelprt' < Dump.sql]]]